# Redshift querying data on dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to query data from redshift table.

I have a users table with columns such as *name*, *age*, *gender* and *created_at* for example:

```
|----|-----|------|----------|
|name|age  |gender|created_at|
------------------------------
|X   | 24  | F    | some_date|
______________________________
```

I need to query above table, in such a way that I have additional columns such as *created_this_week*, *created_last_week*, *created_last_4_week*, *current_month*, *last_month* etc
Additional flag columns should be 'Y' for conditions such as data is from last week, current week, current month, last month, last 4 weeks (excluding this week) so last 4 weeks starting last week etc, something like below.

```
|----|-----|------|-----------|------------|---------|-----------|------------|---------|
|name|age  |gender|created_at |current_week|last_week|last_4_week|current_mnth|last_mnth|
_________________________________________________________________________________________
| X  | 24  |  F   |CURRENTDATE|      Y     |   N     |     N     |    Y       |   N     |
_________________________________________________________________________________________
| F  | 21  |  M   | lst_wk_dt |      N     |   Y     |     Y     | Depends    | depends |
_________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I am new to PostgresSQL and Redshift, and still in my learning phase, I spent past few hrs trying to do this myself but was unsuccessful. I'd really appreciate if someone can help me out with this one.

Comment: Are you defining a week as inside the current Sun-Sat, or are you defining it as last 7 days, regardless of the current day of the week?

Comment: Hi Tim, week would be Monday to sun, as a default.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `case` expressions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when created_at >= now() - interval '1 week' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as week1,
       (case when created_at >= now() - interval '4 week' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as week4,
       . . .
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Are these functions supported in redshift?

Comment: Gordon's answer should run in Redshift without any issues AFAIK +1.

Comment: sounds good. One more question, created_at >= now() - interval '1 week' = will this return Y from today - 7 days, or last week as last Monday to last Sunday? last week in my case is from Feb 10 to Feb 16.

Comment: @user3035168 . . . Your question is not clear on what you mean by those constructs.  If you want a "calendar" week, then use `date_trunc('week', now())`.